# Woocommerce products per page not displaying properly

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have set the 9 products to show per page. On the first few pages, it shows correctly but after a couple of pages it reduces the number of products per page, it shows 7, 4, 6 or 3 on one page.
https://cheezainetc.com/shop/
check out the pages after 50
What can be the issue there?

Comment: Hello, could you please give a minimal example of your code ? You will find here guidance on how to [create an example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and how to [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Answer (score 1):

Please deactivate all plugins one by one to check which one is causing this issue.

Or

just change the no. of products to display in a row in Woocommerce Customizer

That might solve the problem

Comment: Tried that but the problem is still there.

Comment: Number of products per row is 3 http://prntscr.com/nzybs2
It's fine up to page 45 but on page 46 it shows 7 products http://prntscr.com/nzycot after that it shows 6 products

Answer (score 0):

try this, paste in your functions.php

```html
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', 'new_loop_shop_per_page', 20 );

function new_loop_shop_per_page( $cols ) {
  // $cols contains the current number of products per page based on the value stored on Options -> Reading
  // Return the number of products you wanna show per page.
  $cols = 9;
  return $cols;
}
```

If problem is still there, change your theme to wordpress default 2016 theme (more compatible then other wp free themes), and check.
It Can be theme compatible issue with newer version of wp and woocommerce.

Comment: I had done this by using the same code you provided as well as with theme options but the results are the same. Also, I changed the theme before I was using flatsome now I am using woodmart same results on both.
Any other suggestions?